# (anydesk:15722): Gtk-CRITICAL Error while launching Anydesk

Tags: 20.04, gtk, anydesk

I am getting all these errors while trying to launch anydesk on ubuntu 20.04. Can anyone help me in this regards ?

```
anydesk

(anydesk:15722): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:14:09.829: IA__gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(anydesk:15722): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:14:09.832: IA__gtk_widget_set_tooltip_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(anydesk:15722): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:14:09.837: IA__gtk_signal_connect_full: assertion 'GTK_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(anydesk:15722): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:14:09.837: IA__gtk_signal_connect_full: assertion 'GTK_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: Today my PC freezes while upgrading packages, after fix the boot with `dpkg --configure -a` Anydesk stopped working, throwing errors like that. Icon of Anydesk is missing. Other icons like the GIMP tools ones are missing too. I been looking for a solution to this and didn't find anything. Edit: I'm using Kubuntu 20.04, so I didn't tryied installing `gnome-themes-standard` yet as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/791965/748508), just in case, but I will try it if any other soultion comes out.